# Audio player with predetermined songs, and page transitions. best language

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mp3, trackbar, axwindowsmediaplayer

My dad's birthday is coming up. As a child/youth he recorder music of the radio (as many did then) and catalogued them.

I want to create a audio player that displays the songs similar to the way he wrote them ( image linked at bottom).
Has a play all for that page but also has the function to play individual songs. 
If possible I would like a page turn animation when switching between pages.
I wold like it to be possible to jump to certain pages e.g page a, page b etc.

I have seen how to create simple media players where you open a file. However I haven't been able to see what I am after.

The layout I am thinking of is the song list top, and Controls at bottom.

My question(s) is which language is best for this and how best to go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thought I'd best add that I do not know programming and will be learning what I need for this project as I go. So if possible could you explain your help or indicate which part of it I will need to Google.

[image]

UPDATE

Thank you for the replies. I went with VB as suggested and would love some feedback if nobody minds. As I learned more I kept changing my design so it has taken a while to get back to you.

My plan now is to:
*Implement any changes recommended
*Change a little of the gui - 
       +Change the image of the Insert Tape and Play tape buttons
       +Remove the Window media player (Mark not visible) and polish off the control buttons
*Use FormB as the template for the rest of the pages
*Look into compiling the program
   +Test on second computer and laptop
   + Possible test on my brothers computer if he is willing to download it

As well as putting the code here I have uploaded the project to Dropbox. There are two version. With music files (62.8 MB and without 5.75 MB. Please note the files are not the copyrighted songs I have substituted them with royalty free alternatives (please see below for attribution). I I changed the file names instead of code to make it easier should I forget to change it back.

Ok the code was too long to add in so uploaded it to GithubGist

**FormB vb**  https://gist.github.com/Phoenix830/6cc03bc9bb54bdd98aaf4641acaef075

**FormB.Designer VB**  https://gist.github.com/Phoenix830/3f347129ebc7c4d5410c9b44a7df9a81

**Custom Controls** -
**Lab_But vb** https://gist.github.com/Phoenix830/d7bd00b16e08f116dbf12159e3d464af

**Trackbar vb** https://gist.github.com/Phoenix830/4e90cf4df9a3ed694e4b9aa3dc60ead6

**Zip files**
No music https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdjlc1648qi4bpd/Cassette%20Tapes%20-%20No%20Music.rar?dl=0

With Music https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1m5zh0449385zn/Cassette%20Tapes.rar?dl=0

I think that is everything about my current code. This is Attributes and source notes.

**Music**
Title Kevin MacLeod (incompetech.com)
Licensed under Creative Commons: By Attribution 3.0
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

```
01-Barry_Manilow_-_Mandy.mp3   = Arroz Con Pollo.mp3
02-Barry_Manilow-New_York_City_Rhythm = Cheery Monday.mp3
03-Barry_Manilow_-_Looks_Like_We_Made_It = Galway.mp3
04-Barry_Manilow_-_Can't_Smile_Without_You = Glitter Blast
05-Barry_Manilow-Ready_to_Take_a_Chance_Again = Industrious Ferret
06-Barry_Manilow-Tryin'_to_Get_the_Feeling_Again = Le Grand Chase
07-Barry_Manilow-Could_It_Be_Magic = Nouvelle Noel
08-Barry_Manilow_-_Copacabana  = Onion Capers
S2-01-Barry_Manilow-It's_a_Miracle = Teddy Bear Waltz
S2-02-Barry_Manilow-All_the_Time = Unholy Knight
S2-03-Barry_Manilow-I_Write_the_Songs  = Zazie
```

This flaged up as an error if I didn't mark it as code

**TrackBar**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1m5zh0449385zn/Cassette%20Tapes.rar?dl=0

I have tried removing some excess code and still have to delete commented out sections that I don't need. I don't understand this enough and can not find enough information online to implement this in my own code using this just as a guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gi_JFAavM4

Getting MP3 info
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?409651-RESOLVED-How-to-check-the-song-playing-in-Windows-Media-Player

I can not fully remember all the forums, Youtube videos and Microsoft documents I viewed. I will try to add them if I find them as I go over my notes.

These last few links may or may not be overkill but thought worth adding encase they are useful to someone else

Also updated keywords. If they are wrong let me know and I will change them

Comment: ahh so touchy. Happy birthday to dad. I suggest you surprise him with a nice gift (iPOD maybe and find a way to convert and upload his songs) because you don't have any programming backgrounds and I'm afraid you won't finish this task in time. Reschedule this task for his 80th :). Wish him long life.

Comment: Having had this idea several years ago, I had put it off because I didn't know where to start. Asking just a few weeks before his birthday was always going to be a bit ambitious. He will now be getting it for Xmas.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest languages to learn and to easily create an interface i would say is actually Visual Basic in Visual Studio, do download that and google things like "how to play audio file in VB.NET" and "how to add directories to list in VB.NET" and try to use the directories in the list (and when a song reaches it's end) just start on the next one in the list. I would use a ListBox for this. Tell me if you need more help, i would be glad to help you program it, if you need.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to go down one route to find that it wasn't working for me.

I have now got a basic player working (mostly the way I want ti). After further reading I have changed my thinking on the way of getting the result. I had wanted to have posted an update but will do so once I  have my first form completed